# Aptana Studio 3: allow more than ~1300MB memory for JVM

Tags: memory, java, eclipse, 32-vs-64-bit, aptana-studio

*Moved from Stack Overflow.*

I'm running Aptana Studio 3.6.1 on 64-bit Windows 7.

Aptana site states that the IDE is compatible with 64-bit environments. When attempting to use a 64-bit Java version, the IDE doesn't load.

I read that the 64-bit compatibility means that a 64-bit OS is supported, but the IDE itself is restricted to a 32-bit Java environment (essentially limiting the maximum allowed memory to be used).

My PC has a quad-core processor and 16GB of RAM, but Aptana is still so damn slow.

Is there any way to allow more than the 32-bit limited max heap size for Aptana Studio? Eclipse seemingly allows this, but for some reason Aptana doesn't (Aptana is derived from Eclipse).

Currently my (working) `AptanaStudio3.ini` looks like the following:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1386M
--launcher.XXPermSize
512M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-name
Aptana Studio 3
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\client\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xms512M
-Xmx1386M
-Xverify:none
-XX:PermSize=768M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1386M
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:CompileThreshold=100
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

If I attempt to change the `-vm` argument to a 64-bit Java executable/dll, the IDE fails on startup (either with `Cannot start Java virtual machine` or dumps the config with `exit 13`).

If I attempts to increase the `-Xmx` and `XXMaxPermSize` above the value 1386M the IDE fails to start with `Cannot start Java virtual machine`.

There is that `--launcher.library` bit which reads `win32` and `x86`, which instigates that the launcher cannot handle 64-bits at all. Is the launcher system itself limited to 32-bits and if so, could I "roll my own" to start Aptana in 64-bit mode?

(Note: I've seen lots of answers stating that "just using the 32-bit Java" fixes everything. I'm specifically interested in running Aptana on a 64-bit Java version, as the 32-bit version seemingly limits resource usage severely.)

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize=1386M edit it.

Comment: @sttr I stated in my question that increasing the value prevents Aptana Studio from starting.

Comment: @ojrack I used to solve the inverse problem. The smallest amount of memory for the application and the greatest speed. Rather the issue is associated with the garbage collector and memory pool java machine. When implicitly garbage heap memory occupy approximately twice the size of the maximum specified boundary. In fact, you allocate these parameters 4Gb. If you need a lot more - then put x64 Aptana and use x64 java VM.